# Merging a closed question with an open question.....Some problems here

Tags: discussion, close, merge

A moderator merged one question with another, moving the comments to the deleted question to the merged one.  However, I found that my post no longer really applied and I deleted it.

I really question the use of a merging as the answers and their reference may now be irrelevant or seem strange.

I'd like to strongly suggest that instead of merging, the old question (with its answers) be simply closed and a reference to the other question be placed.

Comment: Can you please provide links to the questions you're talking about?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/290122/change-ownership-of-a-file-owned-by-current-user-without-using-sudo-closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My apologies i misread one of the questions ... twice. They shouldn't have been merged.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the questions weren't really "exact duplicates", and hence wouldn't really have been suitable for merging.  As Mark asked, a reference to the question(s) involved would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I'm not quite sure why those two were merged. Normally merging only happens when the questions are totally identical, almost to the word (for example, a cross-post that got migrated here).

Comment: Really. I know I only migrate when content is nigh identical, which happens due to two sources: double-posts (rare), and migrated cross-posts.